# Откуда PHP берёт данные формы, если формы не было

Tags: php

Имеется следующий код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Секретная страница</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if ((!isset($_POST['name'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
?>
    <h1>Пожалуйста, войдите</h1>
    <p>Это секретная страница.</p>
    <form method="post" action="secret.php">
    <p><label for="name">Имя пользователя:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="15" /></p>
    <p><label for="password">Пароль:</label> 
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15" /></p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Войти</button>    
    </form>
<?php
  } else if(($_POST['name']=='user') && ($_POST['password']=='pass')) {
    echo '<h1>Вот она!</h1>
          <p>Бьемся об заклад, что вы безумно рады возможности видеть эту секретную страницу.</p>';
  } else {
    echo '<h1>Уходите!</h1>
          <p>Вы не имеете права использовать этот ресурс.</p>';
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

В браузере эта страница выглядит так:
[image: страница браузера]

Откуда в массиве _POST имеются индексы "name" и "password" ?

`if ((!isset($_POST['name'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {`

если на данную страницу я не переходил заполняя какую-либо форму ?

Почему из одного файла PHP создаются две HTML страницы (после введения данных формы)? Я думал, что одному

Comment: Что значит откудо? Вы когда форму пересылаете они там появляются. А что-бы проверить, что они переслались, и существует проверка `isset`

Comment: А вот эта строчка неверна `if(($_POST['name']=='user') && ($_POST['password']=='pass'))` . если этих елемнетов нет, вылетит птич....ошибка.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman Не вылетит. Он первым `if` проверяет на `isset`оба поля

Comment: А точно, не доглядел. Извините!

Comment: @Антон там происходит проверка - если есть такие элементы и они правильные, то показывается секретная страница. Если есть такие элемнеты и они не правильные - то сообщение о том, чтоб юзер уходил. А если нет таких элементов, то показать форму. А вот после отправки формы, эти элементы появятся и тогда идет снова проверка :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует почитать об `if..else` ([условные операторы](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?co))

Функция `isset` проверяет, установлена ли переменная.

Запись `!isset($_POST['name'])` равнозначна `isset($_POST['name'])===false`.

Можно показать так:

```
// Если $_POST['name'] или $_POST['password'] не установлены
if ((!isset($_POST['name'])) || (!isset($_POST['password']))) {
    // HTML код формы

// Если в $_POST['name'] значение 'user' и в $_POST['password'] значение 'pass'
} elseif(($_POST['name']=='user') && ($_POST['password']=='pass')) {
    echo '<h1>Вот она!</h1><p>Бьемся об заклад, что вы безумно рады возможности видеть эту секретную страницу.</p>';

// Иначе выводим сообщение 'Вы не имеете права использовать этот ресурс'
} else {
    echo '<h1>Уходите!</h1><p>Вы не имеете права использовать этот ресурс.</p>';
}
```

Comment: Так так и показано, нет разве?

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой ответ. Может хоть по комментариям в коде поймет принцип работы if..else

Comment: @RaZik, очень сильно затупил

Comment: Понял, что происходит. Форма обрабатывается этим же PHP кодом

Comment: Если файл с кодом формы имеет название secret.php, тогда да)